# Reorganizing Excel Data

Tags: excel

I receive reports from an operational system that provide hourly values in this format, where column A is the asset name, column B is the military time, and Column C is the data point:

```
Column A  Column B   Column C  
Asset A    10:00      Value  
Asset A    22:00      Value  
Asset B    10:00      Value  
Asset B    22:00      Value  
Asset C    10:00      Value  
Asset C    22:00      Value  
Asset D    10:00      Value  
Asset D    22:00      Value
```

The reports are always consistent in the number of data values per asset (in this case - two), but the reports can vary in length based on the number of assets in the reporting group.

I would like to create a separate table that has the asset names as columns and the data values as rows.  In this example, I would end up with:

```
Time    Asset A   Asset B   Asset C   Asset D
10:00    Value     Value     Value     Value 
22:00    Value     Value     Value     Value
```

Ultimately, I would produce a graph where the time is the x-axis label, the y-axis is scaled to match the value, and the data series are the assets.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you looked into pivot tables?

Comment: have you tried using a Pivot Table?

Comment: Yes, but without much success.  Pivot Tables would require selection of the array in each report.  Since the length of the reports varies by the number of assets and the number of data points per asset in each report, building both the pivot tables and graph is a time-consuming process.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Pivot Table. (Sorry it's on my Mac). Get around the length of data changing by making your data into an Excel Table.

[image]